# Is it possible to make the first diagonal element of a non-diagonal matrix equal to $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a matrix $A$ is scalar times the unit matrix $I$, it is only similar to itself.
If $A$ is not scalar times the unit matrix, is it always the case that there exists $B$ such that the $(1,1)$ element (the first diagonal element) of $BAB^{-1}$ is $0$?

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $B$ as a change of basis matrix, then your problem amounts to finding a basis $\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$ of $\mathbb{K}^n$ for which $Ae_1$ is in the subspace spanned by $b_2,\dots ,b_n$. To achieve this, note that by hypothesis there must be some vector $v$ such that $Av$ is not a multiple of $v$; thus $v$ and $Av$ are linearly independent, and you can complete them to get a basis of $\Bbb K^n$. This basis has the required property, as $Ab_1=Av=b_2$.

Comment: What do you mean by $e_1, /dots , e_n$?

Comment: @sacch It was supposed to be $b_1,\dots,b_n$, I fixed it.